# Opera irc chat disconnecting

Tags: chat

How do I make sure I don't get disconnected from a chat room?
I'm using Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IRC is a pretty resilient protocol, but you can never be assured you'll never disconnect. Even assuming a perfect server that never has issues or netsplits, it's entirely out of your hands. If your internet connection remains entirely stable, you'll stay, if it doesn't, you'll ping out.

If your internet connection is /really/ unstable, consider using a [bouncer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BNC_(software)) or running a terminal client (like irssi) on an external server that DOES have a very stable connection.